# moved Class location and now can't pickle-load object of that class

Tags: python-import, importerror

in my project I had a submodule called pakreader from whick I was importing in this way:

```
from pakreader.pak import Pak
```

then I moved pak.py in the app/ folder
so that now I have to import

```
from pakreader.app.pak import Pak
```

Unfortunately I had saved some object of class Pak in a pickle file and now when I try to unpickle them i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pakreader.pak'
```

Is there a way to fix this?
Many thanks
Regards

EDIT: the **init**.py file is there, the problem is that the path these object were saved with (the old version module) has changed in the new version

Comment: Can you give some more detailed informations about your folder structure? Anyways I asume you are missing a `__init__.py` file, which creates a module you can work with. Otherwise files from subdirectories can't be imported.